# Как правильно прочитать определенное количество байт в структуру?

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть структура:

```
struct map {
   void* key;
   void* value;
}
```

Я читаю весь двоичный файл в буфер:

```
void* buffer = malloc(size);

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

fread(buffer, size, 1, file);
```

И мне нужно определенное количество байт из буфера замапить на структуру. Т.е. допустим достать 40 байт из буфера, 20 байт в поле key и 20 в value, и так пройти по всему буферу и вернуть как массив map'ов. Собственно вопрос: Как правильно прочитать 20 байт в key и 20 байт в value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим, судя по имени структуры (`map`), что предполагается именно маппинг, т.е. доступ к данным непосредственно в буфере.

Тогда, если использовать вашу структуру с указателями, то помимо буфера надо еще выделить память под массив структур, далее заполнить его адресами в буфере и вернуть.

Получим что-то вроде

```
struct map * 
foo (FILE *f, size_t size)
{
   char *buffer = malloc(size); // предположим, что size в самом деле кратен 40 и проверять это не будем
   struct map *p = malloc(size / 40 * sizeof(struct map));

   rewind(f);
   fread(buffer, size, 1, f);

   size_t i = 0;
   for (char *t = buffer; t < buffer + size; t += 40, i++) {
      p[i].key = t; p[i].value = t + 20;
   }

   return p;
}
```

По окончании обработки удаляете буфер

```
struct map *m_map = foo(input_file, data_size);

.....
  for (int i = 0; i < data_size / 40; i++)
    printf("key: %s  value: %s\n", m_map[i].key, m_map[i].value);
.....

 free (m_map[0].key);
```

и потом map (полученный массив структур)

```
 free (m_map);
```

Если же хотите работать непосредственно с данными в буфере, то надо использовать вот такую структуру

```
struct c_map {
  char key[20];
  char value[20];
};
```

Тогда получаем вот такую функцию для чтения даннных

```
 struct c_map *
 bar (FILE *f, size_t size)
 {
    char *buffer = malloc(size); // предположим, что size в самом деле кратен 40 и проверять это не будем

    rewind(f);
    fread(buffer, size, 1, f);

    return (struct c_map *)buffer;
 }
```

Получаете массив отмапленных на буфер структур и по окончании обработки удаляете буфер  вот так

```
 struct c_map *m_map = bar(input_file, data_size);
 .....
  for (int i = 0; i < data_size / 40; i++)
    printf("key: %s  value: %s\n", m_map[i].key, m_map[i].value);
 .....
 free(m_map);
```

Конечно, в обеих вариантах, если после каждых 19 байт в файле не будет двоичного нуля (терминатора строки), то и в полях структуры он не появится.

Comment: Последний способ мне понравился, но мне бы хотелось хранить в мапе не только строки, но и числа, как этого можно добиться?

Comment: Нет. Во втором случае структуры `c_map` размещаются в *точности по тем же адресам памяти*, что и данные в буфере. Т.е. поля структуры должны по своему типу совпадать с данными файла. Если у вас более сложная, чем пара полей по 20 байт структура данных в файле, то опишите конкретно ее в вопросе

Comment: Еще вопрос, почему вы указатель на начало куска памяти от malloc сохраняете в char* переменную, а не void*?

Comment: Для Си это без разницы

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя просто так взять и считать указатели. Вам нужно записывать каждую структуру с указанием размеров, примерно как

```
map m;
...
int len = strlen(m.key);
fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
fwrite(m.key,len+1,1,file);
len = strlen(m.value);
fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
fwrite(m.value,len+1,1,file);
```

а потом, при чтении, читать поочередно...

```
map m;
...
int len;
fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
m.key = malloc(len);
fread(m.key,len+1,1,file);
fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,file);
m.value = malloc(len);
fread(m.value,len+1,1,file);
```

Примерно так.

Иначе вы просто записываете и читаете указатели, а не данные, на которые они указывают.

Ели бы вы описали структуру как

```
struct map {
   char key[20];
   char value[20];
};
```

тогда дело другое, можно читать-писать непосредственно. Но в указанном вами варианте это невозможно.

Comment: Код весьма странный, в части m.key, там будет просто какой-то адрес в памяти. Можно просто сделать массив структур, т.к. физического смысла m.key без разыменования значения иметь не будет(но добавится оверхид на поиск дубликата при добавлении значения в мап), а если файл очень будет большим код может работать долго. Ключом мапа обычно делают тип который можно легко сравнить с другим значением - будь int или std::string.

Comment: правильнее и быстрее будет выяснить размер файла через fseek()/ftell() выделить буфер в памяти описать структуру typedef struct {union{ char[20] key; void* pkey;} union{ char[20] value; void *pvalue;}} MYMAP, *PMYMAP; и манипулировать прочитанным буфером через как массивом MYMAP. вида ((PMYMAP)buffer)[0].key ((PMYMAP)buffer)[0].value как то так.

Comment: Т.е. просто брать из файла по очереди, 20 байт для ключа, а потом 20 байт для значения, не выводя предварительно в буфер?

Comment: @Yakov Дайте свой ответ с полным нормальным кодом, потому что из ваших комментариев совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите сказать; боюсь, вы только запутаете автора вопроса. К автору - покажите, как вы создаете свои объекты, потому что вы тоже несколько путаетесь в показаниях :) - у вас ключ и значение указатели? Откуда тогда по 20 байт? Или это указатели на 20-байтные строки? Словом, приведите более полный код.

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать вот так

```
struct map
{
  uint8_t key[40];
  uint8_t value[40];
}__attribute__((packed));

uint8_t * buffer = malloc(size);
fread(buffer, size, 1, file);

map * begin_map = (map*)buffer;
map * current_map = begin_map;
map * end_map = (map*)(bufffer + size);

/*теперь к поля структуры можно обращаться  */
current_map->key;
current_map->value;
/*перемещаться между структурами */ 
current_map += number;
current_map -= number;
/*но нужно проверять не вышли за пределы данных*/
if (current_map > begin_map) {
   ...
}
if (current_map < end_map) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так. если я правильно все понял. ногами не бейте. писал в блокноте по памяти. может где ошибся.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef 
struct 
{
    union
    { 
        char[20] key; 
        void* pkey;
    } 
    union
    { 
        char[20] value; 
        void *pvalue;
    }
} MYMAP, *PMYMAP;

void main()
{
    void* buffer;
    int i;
    long size;
    fpos_t *pos; /* fpos_t определен в stdio.h */
    pos = &l;
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fgetpos(file, (fpos_t*) &size); 
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(size+2);
    fread(buffer, size,  size, file);
    //после чтения файла в буфер просто делим его на куски. 
    for(i=0;i<size/sizeof(MYMAP);i++)
    {
        //т.к. это пример, положим, что значения key и value в файле завершаются нолем и будут выводиться как си-строка. если нет эту часть надо исправить.
        printf("key = %s, value = %s", 
        PMYMAP(buffer+i*sizeof(MYMAP)).key,
        PMYMAP(buffer+i*sizeof(MYMAP)).value);
    }
}
```

Comment: да еще у структуры есть особенность. в памяти она выравнивается на границу слова или двойного слова, зависит от компилятора в общем. и если размер ее членов не будет кратен этому выравниванию, то компилятор ее увеличит до недостающих кратных байт, чтобы повысить скорость доступа к памяти. и этот момент надо учесть и компилятору сообщить, что де выравнивание к этой структуре не применять, в VC это делалось через #pragma push / #pragma pop.

Comment: Для переносимости у функции `main` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int`